# Как обновить checkbox в ASP.NET

Tags: c#, ajax, html5, asp.net

У меня есть два паршала, в одном список, а в другом открываеться более детальная информация после того как нажать на запись в списке. Когда открывается детальная информация, есть чекбокс "active". Как мне сделать чтобы после того как я нажму на этот чекбокс и нажму кнопку "Сохранить", чекбокс обновлялся и в главном списке. За рисунок простите, кроме паинта негде нарисовать. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Views**

**List**

```
<table class="table details-list-table hoverTable" id="selectedRow">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Active</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model != null)
                {
                    foreach (var s in Model)
                    {
                        <tr style="cursor: pointer" data-id="@s.sys_id" title="Edit" class="hover">
                            <td class="centered">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => s.sys_name)
                            </td>
                            <td class="centered">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => s.sys_active)
                            </td>
                            <td class="centered">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => s.sys_type)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Edit view**

```
                <table DisplayTables">
                @if (Model != null)
            {
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Name")
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(s => s.sys_name, new { htmlAttributes = new { style = "Width:180px" } })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(s => s.sys_id)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Active")
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(s => s.sys_active)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayName("Type")
                        </th>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(s => s.SystemType)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
```

Comment: Приведите код вашего view

Comment: @AK    Извигите, добавил :)

Comment: checkboxObject.checked = true|false или  более подробно  
`document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true`

Comment: если непонятно то вот тут  https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_checkbox_order

Comment: @Eikhner Спасибо. Попробую разобраться.

Comment: задать можно и так $("#id").prop("checked", false|true); а проверить так 
if( $("#id").is(":checked"))

Comment: View и Edit на одной и той же странице (по одному и тому же URL) находятся? (при клике в списке unHide'идтся блок с редактированием) А то у меня уже есть сомнения, что я вам правильно сказал в [другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/703261/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%98%d0%94-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85/703291#703291).