# Поле видимости ИД в паршалах

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Теоретический вопрос, в один view вложены два partial. Если в одном прописан id(например id=name) видна ли id из другого partial?

Comment: Господа, ну зачем сразу минусовать? У человека был вопрос в связи с [другим вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702985/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-id-%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0), пытается разобраться.

Comment: Когда html-страница сформируется и отправится в клиентский браузер не будет вообще никакой информации, где какие partial находились, это будет одна единая страница. Возможно, вам имеет смысл пояснить, какую задачу вы решаете? Зачем вам нужно из одного partial что-то знать о другом (id, class и т.п.)?

Comment: @AK "Когда html-страница сформируется и отправится в клиентский браузер не будет вообще никакой информации, где какие partial находились"  - Вот эту информацию я и не смог найти в интернете. Оформите пожалуста как ответ и за его отмечу как правельный.

Comment: Я могу и оформить, но вы ведь так и не ответили, чего вы конкретно хотите от своей задачи с id'шниками. Вы можете даже прописать их явно и жёстко, но возможно лишь приучите себя забивать гвозди микроскопом и копипастить чужой код из интенета. На мете есть тема про [XY проблему](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/213987), почитайте -- возможно вы поймёте, что не зря из вас вытаскивают задачу, а не дают ответ на конкретный вопрос.

Comment: @AK Мне нужна id для того чтобы нажимая один чекбокс включались два. Я спрашивал об этом тут. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702810/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-checkbox-%D0%B2-asp-net

Comment: @AK У вас нет предположений как это можно решить?

Comment: Да, вам лучше сделать через id, а не через class (и искать именно через GetElementById, а не GetElemensByClass). В том вопросе, что вы удалили был приведён правильный синтаксис. А вот почему у вас в id не попало значение -- это другой вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не хватает фундаментальных знаний про работу клиентской и серверной стороны.

Всё разделение на отдельные partial имеет смысл только на стороне сервера, вы делаете логические блоки, которые можете комбинировать для своего удобства так как вам нужно. Можно повторно использовать код, избегать копипасты и т.п.

Но работа сервера, неважно будет это страница на php или asp.net mvc в итоге сводится к тому, что рано или поздно будет собран итоговый Html (простая строка), которая попадёт в браузер пользователя.

В этой странице будет один большой кусок кода и никаких уже следов partial не сохранится.

---

N.B. При условии, что вы ***выводите оба Partial на одной и той же веб-странице***. Уточнение странное, но [похоже нужное](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/702810/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-checkbox-%d0%b2-asp-net) - с учётом того, в каком контексте этот вопрос задаётся.